# How to overflow:scroll on sticky div

Tags: css, menu, overflow, sticky

I'm creating a WordPress theme and I'd like to make sticky horizontal menu which has overflow:scroll. What happens is when I'm trying to do that it's either not working or it hides the content.

Below I post the code.

HTML:

```css
.container
{
 height:100vh;
 
 
}

body
{
 background-color:grey;
 
}

#navmenu 
{
 position:sticky;
 height:70px;
 text-align:center;
 overflow:scroll;
 border-top:1px solid white; 
}

#navmenu ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
 text-align:center;
 min-width:100%;
 
 
}

#navmenu li {
    float: left;
 font-size:14px;
 text-align:center;
 
 
 
}

#navmenu li a {
    display: inline-block;
    /*color: white;*/
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
 
}

#navmenu li a:hover
{
 background-color:#111;
}



.logo
{
 height:50px;
 float:left;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="about.css">
 
</head>



<body>
 
<div class="container">
<div id="logo"></div>

<div id="navmenu">
 
 <ul>
  <li><img style="height:70px" src="img/logo.png"></li>
  <li><a href="#">OPTION</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OPTION <br>OPTION</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OPTION <br>OPTION</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OPTION <br>OPTION</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OPTION</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OPTION OPTION <br>OPTION</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OPTION</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OPTION <br>OPTION</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">OPTION</a></li>
 </ul>
 
 
 
</div>



</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The menu in your demo scrolls..? Do you want the menu to move with the  rest of the page?

Comment: what is the purpose of overflow:scroll; here ? . looks awfull. position:sticky only works in ff and chrome if you allow experimental CSS

Comment: I mean to keep the menu in one line whatever happens, can be made as a responsive one, but both didn't work for me. And the menu is not scrolling horizontally @ovokuro

Comment: okay, to trigger sticky you also need to set a coordonate where it is suppose to stick (top:0; or else )

Comment: Where do you mean? In #navmenu section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author of the question has clarified (see comments) that they want the entire page to scroll horizontally, not just the nav bar.

Here's a JSFiddle solution: jsfiddle.net/qwjshv9s/1

There are two parts to this solution.

1. Don't let anything except the body scroll.

Get rid of all `overflow:scroll` properties present and put `overflow-x:auto` on the body itself.

2. Don't allow the menu to wrap.

Apply `whitespace:nowrap` to the `<ul>` and switch the `<li>` elements from `float:left` to `display:inline-block`.

--

By the way, to allow scrolling *horizontally* only, you can use:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
```

This only allows scrolling on the X axis. If you don't want the scrollbar to always be there, you can do

```
overflow-x: auto;
```

and it will scroll only when needed.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I've tried that and unfortunately it hides my content as I make the windows smaller instead showing scrollbar.

Comment: Both solutions works basically the same, they're just hiding the content instead of making a scrollbar. What can be the reason of that?

Comment: Are you asking about having the scrollbar show up visibly? Many browsers will visually hide the scrollbar when it isn't actively being used. If you want to make sure it's _visible_ (and not just technically there) then that's another issue entirely.

Comment: No, what I mean there's no problem with scrollbar, the content is just being cut when I make the window smaller. There's no way to really scroll it. The part of site that cannot fit in the window just disappears.

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle demo using my suggested `width: 1000px` solution: https://jsfiddle.net/qwjshv9s/. The content of the navmenu is wider than the page and overflows. But you can scroll horizontally to see it. Is that what you wanted, or did you have something else in mind?

Comment: Perhaps you want the entire page to scroll horizontally instead of just the nav bar?

Comment: Here's a JSFiddle of what it would look like to have the whole body scroll instead of just the nav: https://jsfiddle.net/qwjshv9s/1/ Essentially, you need to get rid of all `overflow:scroll` you have and put `overflow-x:auto` on the `body` itself. Then you need to apply `whitespace: nowrap` to your `UL` and switch the `LI` elements from `float: left` to `display: inline-block` (this prevents wrapping).

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I wanted, to make the entire page scrollable. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your nav in an additional div with a defined width. See snippet:

```css
.container {
  height: 100vh;
}
body {
  background-color: grey;
}
#navmenu {
  position: sticky;
  height: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: scroll;
  border-top: 1px solid white;
}

#nav-inner {
  width: 10000px; 
 }
#navmenu ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  min-width: 100%;
}
#navmenu li {
  float: left;
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
}
#navmenu li a {
  display: inline-block;
  /*color: white;*/
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#navmenu li a:hover {
  background-color: #111;
}
.logo {
  height: 50px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="logo"></div>

  <div id="navmenu">
    <div id="nav-inner">
      <ul>
        <li>
          <img style="height:70px" src="img/logo.png">
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">OPTION</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">OPTION <br>OPTION</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">OPTION <br>OPTION</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">OPTION <br>OPTION</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">OPTION</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">OPTION OPTION <br>OPTION</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">OPTION</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">OPTION <br>OPTION</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">OPTION</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  </div>



</div>
```

Comment: Is that still gonna be fine as a WordPress theme? I mean will WordPress recognise it as a menu?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest, you'd have to do some testing. I don't know of another way with CSS to achieve what you want, sorry!

Comment: That's fine, thank you very much. But to be honest with you I got some problem with that solution. It is working perfectly in "Run code snippet" but when I'm trying it in actual code editor and save it it's not working really. What can it be?

Comment: That's impossible for me to answer as I don't have access to what you're seeing. Try Brenton's answer. It might be the case that adding a large width to the nav without an additional container will work.